# post with whatwg-fetch is working but no data being posted

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, fetch

Im having issues with a POST with "whatwg-fetch" the response is returnin as 200 but no data is passing.

this is the code on the server...

```
app.post('/promo', function(request, response) {

  response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  var promo = new PromoItem();
  promo.imgUrl = request.body.imgUrl;
  promo.name = request.body.name;
  promo.description = request.body.description;
  promo.category = request.body.category;

  console.log('----------');
  console.log(promo.name);
  console.log(request.body.name);
  console.log('----------');
  promo.save(function(err, savedPromo) {
    if (err) {
      responde.status(500).send({
        error: "Something happened, promo not saved !"
      });
    } else {

      response.status(200).send("Success !");
    }
  });
});
```

both **promo.name** and **request.body.name** are returning as undefined.

The code on the client..

```
setPromo = () => {
  const options = {

    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: "POST",

    mode: 'no-cors',

    body: JSON.stringify({
      "imgUrl": "http://via.placeholder.com/900x200",
      "name": "MI POST",
      "description": "MI PRIMER POST",
      "category": "Salud"
    })
  };
  fetch('http://localhost:3010/promo', options).then(function(response) {
    console.log('Status', response.status);
  })
}
```

have manipulated the options with different values but still the same result.

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: should `responde.status` be `response.status`

Comment: seems it wasnt creating any issue. no change on results.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the data is not being parsed. In Express, `POST` bodies can be parsed by `body-parser`. There are usage examples [on the Express website](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html). Essentially, you can use the `body-parser` middleware like this:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

It can also be used on a per-route basis:

```
app.post('/promo', bodyParser.json(), function(request, response) { //...
```

If you are using a version of Express >= 4.16.0, `bodyParser.json` is available as `express.json`. ([source](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json))

Comment: Also, the CORS header might not be helpful in the `POST` response, as CORS tends to be checked via an `OPTIONS` preflight request. (See MDN documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)).

There is a very popular Express middleware package for CORS (simply called `cors`) that can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).

Comment: the code is actually using **app.use(bodyParser.json());** but did not include it in the code sheet. but im gonna try using it inside the route to see what happens. thanks !